# upgrade all outdated pip packages discarding failures

Tags: pip, package, upgrade

I have a bash command to upgrade all pip packages that I installed.

The command is:

```
pip3 list --outdated | cut -d' ' -f1 | tail -n +3 | xargs pip3 install --upgrade
```

The problem is that if one of the packages fails to upgrade, it rolls back deleting the upgrades of the ones that were successful upgraded.

Is there a way to upgrade all outdated packages with a single command discarding the failures of some packages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+upgrade+%22one+by+one%22

Comment: The key is `-n1`: `xargs -n1 pip3 install…`

Comment: which key? By the way the solution in the link you posted worked adding `--user` at the end. Complete command: `pip3 list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U --user`. Thank you anyway

Comment: There's a much more elegant method involving `freeze` and `requirements.txt`, [see here in github comment](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3819#issuecomment-265135462).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I slightly modified the command posted in the *duplicate of* link.

```
pip3 list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U --user
```

Comment: I get an error message "--outdated" can not be used with "freeze" with pip 23.3.2 on python 3.10